# Global number of Fb like and tweets

Tags: twitter, facebook-like

I started writing blogs on blogspot and I wanted to create social networking sharing options. I used the API of Facebook and Twitter to like the article or tweet it. But what I found is that if the like or tweet counter increases only if it is done from my blog page. But sometimes, people like my article from my Facebook wall or retweet it. But these likes or retweets arent counted. Is there any way where I can get the total number?

I  hope I am clear :-)